# How to save the combined content of files with name of current folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to save the combined file with the name of the folder:

```
copy *.* A.txt %CD%.txt
```

But I'm getting syntax error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: You'd need to explain what you're trying to do. Given that `Copy *.* A.txt` copies all files matching the wildcard to `A.txt` and `Copy A.txt + B.txt C.txt` will copy `A.txt` and `B.txt` to `C.txt`, we need you to clarify the task. Additionally, `%CD%` is likely to look like this `C:\Users\YourName`, so I can only assume that you wanted something named thus, `C:\Users\YourName.txt`, so not only could you have used `%UserName%.txt`, _(you may not have access to `C:\Users`)_.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to combine all text files into a text file with the name of the directory.txt, and have them be on the directory prior to the one names?  This is as simple as `Copy *.txt "%CD%.txt"`  If you mean to copy to a separate folder, even just the same folder you could do it in a `FOR` loop, or `copy` then `move` them.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon my best guess of what you're trying to do, you could, [copy](/questions/tagged/copy) to `A.txt`:

```bat
Copy *.* A.txt
```

Then [rename](/questions/tagged/rename) the file:

```bat
Rename A.txt "YourNewName.txt"
```

However, you could probably do both tasks together.

To do that using the name of the current directory of your [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) session:

```bat
For %I In ("%CD%")Do @Copy *.* "%~nxI.txt"
```

---

If you're working in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), then use either:

```bat
@For %%I In ("%CD%")Do @Copy *.* "%%~nxI.txt"
```

Or

```bat
@For %%I In ("%__CD__%.")Do @Copy *.* "%%~nxI.txt"
```

To use the name of the current directory at that point in your script.

Or if you want to use the name of the directory holding the running batch file instead, try:

```bat
@For %%I In ("%~dp0.")Do @Copy *.* "%%~nxI.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to do this on WINDOWS 2000 or greater (and therefore are asking about `CMD` not `DOS`)

As in my comment, perhaps you meant to combine all text files in one directory, to a single file in the directory above it.

This is as simple as `Copy *.txt "%CD%.txt"`

But you may not have permissions to the folder above, to write, or you may want to write it into the same folder as the other text files, or perhaps into a completely separate folder.

In which case you would need to use a simple a `FOR` loop, or `copy` and then `move` the file.

Copy to the same directory as the existing text files:

```
FOR %_ IN ("%CD%") DO @(
  COPY *.txt "%~n_.txt"
)
```

Copy to another arbitrary directory but name them after the directory they came from:

```
FOR %_ IN ("%CD%") DO @(
  COPY *.txt "C:\Path\To\Folder\Where_you_Want_These\%~n_.txt"
)
```